# R plot: Quarterly date not in sequential order

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

sorry for the lack of reproducibility example that I am about to display but I am sure this issue has happened quite a lot when building plots. I have two time series that I want to display (one as a barplot and the other as a line). I also want to use two different Y-axes scales.
To do so I use the following code:

```
Color <- "#FF6347"
priceColor <- rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1)
coeff <- 0.035

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, group =1)) +
  geom_bar( aes(y=YseriesA), stat="identity", size=.1, fill=Color, color="black", alpha=.4) + 
  geom_line( aes(y=YseriesB / coeff), size=1.2, color=priceColor) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "B",
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name="A")
  ) + 
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = Color, size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = priceColor, size=13)
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Most importantly, the variable time I have produced with the following code:

```
data$time <- seq(from = zoo::as.yearqtr("2000-01-01"), to = zoo::as.yearqtr("2019-01-01"), by = 1/4) %>%
  format("Q%q-%Y")
```

[image]

My question, the issue is the following. Why on earth is time not ordered from earlier to later in the X-axes but displays this weird order: Q1-2000, Q1-2001, Q1-2002..... Any help much much appreciated and once again my most sincere apologies for the lack of reproducibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zoo`'s `scale_x_yearqtr` (now that you're using that class!):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  zoo::scale_x_yearqtr(n = 40,
                         format = "Q%q-%Y")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data** (please provide some another time - it doesn't need to be perfect):

```r
library(tibble)
library(zoo)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(y = rnorm(77),
             date = seq(from = zoo::as.yearqtr("2000-01-01"),
                        to   = zoo::as.yearqtr("2019-01-01"),
                        by   = 1/4)
             )
```